# Making magento admin field dependent on more than one value or field?

Tags: magento

First of all I have already seen this question [can a magento adminhtml field depend on more then one field or value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849616/can-a-magento-adminhtml-field-depend-on-more-then-one-field-or-value)
It talks about System/Configuration fields, which is not what I am looking for.

I am trying to create a form in the magento backend. I have a dropdown **Dropdown** with values 1, 2 and 3.
I need the field X to be displayed when I select 1 or 2. How do I do this ?

I am able to display X depending on a single value of the dropdown, not for multiple values.

This is how I have done:

```
$this->setChild('form_after',$this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_form_element_dependence')
            ->addFieldMap($X->getHtmlId(), $Xl->getName())
            ->addFieldMap($dropdown->getHtmlId(), $dropdown->getName())
            ->addFieldDependence($X->getName(), $dropdown->getName(), 1)
);
```

Where `$x` and `$dropdown` are variables which stores `addField()` result

Comment: Did you try with the last parameter of `addFieldDependence` set to an array? I mean `->addFieldDependence($X->getName(), $dropdown->getName(), array(1,2))`.

Comment: Thanks for replying Marius. I tried it now, its not working. Its not showing the field at all.

Answer (score 13):

You can.

**More Fields**:
Just add more dependency:

```
->addFieldDependence($X->getName(), $dropdown_1->getName(), $value_dw_1)
->addFieldDependence($X->getName(), $dropdown_2->getName(),$value_dw_2)
```

**More Values (same field)**:
You should pass an array of of values:

```
->addFieldDependence($X->getName(), $dropdown->getName(), array($value1,value2))
```

if `$value1/$value2` are numbers it is better you cast them to string or it could not work properly:

```
->addFieldDependence($X->getName(), $dropdown->getName(), array((string)$value1,(string)value2))
```

There reason for this issue can be tracked down in `js/mage/adminhtml/form.js` in the method `trackChange` at one point you see this code :

```
...
// define whether the target should show up
    var shouldShowUp = true;
    for (var idFrom in valuesFrom) {
        var from = $(idFrom);
        if (valuesFrom[idFrom] instanceof Array) {
            if (!from || valuesFrom[idFrom].indexOf(from.value) == -1) {
                shouldShowUp = false;
            }
        } else {
            if (!from || from.value != valuesFrom[idFrom]) {
                shouldShowUp = false;
            }
        }
    }
....
```

you see that in case `valuesFrom[idFrom]` it is used `indexOf` to check if show the field or not, this cause problem because, it think, `indexOf` do a comparison taking care of the type and `from.value` it contains a string while in the array `valuesFrom[idFrom]` we have an array of numbers ...

This issue not occur in case of a single value because `from.value != valuesFrom[idFrom]` is not taking care of the type

Answer (score -1):

Simple fix for this would be to use jquery in admin section.

1. Include jquery file in your admin section, you do this by including this in layout file

```html
<reference name = "head">
  <action method="addJs"><script>jquery/jquery.js</script></action>
  <action method="addJs"><script>jquery/jquery.noconflict.js</script></action>
</reference>
```

2. Then in the admin edit form code, you check on click:

> ```
> $fieldset->addField('market_days', 'multiselect', array(
>                             'label'     => Mage::helper('marketmanagement')->__('Select Days'),
>                             'class'     => 'required-entry market-days',
>                             'required'  => true,
>                             'name'      => 'market_days',
>                             'onclick' => ""//jquery code here
> ));
> ```

You can write jquery code to show/hide fields based on the value selected.

Hope this helps

Comment: This is not a correct answer ... magento already allows this, you don't need to add jquery