# Creating dependency between admin form fields in magento does not work

Tags: php, forms, magento

This is an admin form in which I have added a custom tab in order add some custom fields to it. The form works fine. but I need to add `field dependency` for some of my fields.

If the field `zipbasedprice_isrange` is set to `yes`, then I need to show other two fields & if it is set to `no`, then only one field should be shown.

How can I implement this using below form?

Field dependencies should be between `zipbasedprice_isrange`, `zipbasedprice_zip`, `zipbasedprice_zip_from_zip` & `zipbasedprice_zip_to_zip`.

```
public function getFormHtml() {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form(
            array('id' => 'edit_form', 'action' => $this->getData('action'), 'method' => 'post')
        );
    
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_form_renderer_element').
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_form_renderer_fieldset').
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_form_renderer_fieldset_element');


    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('zipbasedprice_fields', array('legend' => Mage::helper('zipbasedprice')->__('Zip Based Price'))
    );

    $default_country = array('label' => 'IN', 'code' => 'India');
    
    $fieldset->addField('zipbasedprice_country', 'select', array(
                    'name' => 'zipbasedprice_country',
                    'label' => Mage::helper('zipbasedprice')->__('Country'),
                    'values'    => Mage::getModel('adminhtml/system_config_source_country')->toOptionArray(),
                    'required' => true,
                    'style' => 'width:275px',
                    'value' => $default_country,
                    'after_element_html' => '<p class="zipbased_comment" style="margin: 0 150px; padding: 3px;"><img style="margin-right: 4px;" src="http://zonepricing.innoexts.com/skin/adminhtml/default/default/images/note_bg.gif" /><small>select the country to apply price</small></p>',
         ));
    
    $regions = array();
    $regions['*'] = '*';
$regionList = Mage::getModel('directory/region')->getResourceCollection()->addCountryFilter('IN')->load();
foreach($regionList as $region){ $regions[$region['code']] = $region['default_name']; }
    
    $fieldset->addField('zipbasedprice_state', 'select', array(
        'name' => 'zipbasedprice_state',
        'label' => Mage::helper('zipbasedprice')->__('Region/State'),
        'values' => $regions,
        'required' => true,
        'style' => 'width:275px',
      ));
    

   $isRange = $fieldset->addField('zipbasedprice_isrange', 'select', array(
        'name' => 'zipbasedprice_isrange',
        'label' => Mage::helper('zipbasedprice')->__('Is Range?'),
        'values' => array(
            array(
                'value' => false,
                'label' => Mage::helper('zipbasedprice')->__('No'),
            ),
            array(
                'value' => true,
                'label' => Mage::helper('zipbasedprice')->__('Yes'),
            )
        ),
       'value' => false,
       'onchange' => 'onIsZipRangeChange()',
       'required' => false,
   'style' => 'width:275px',
      ));
     

    $fieldset->addField('zipbasedprice_zip', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'zipbasedprice_zip',
        'label' => Mage::helper('zipbasedprice')->__('Zip Code'),
        'class' => 'input',
        'required' => true,
    'style' => 'width:268px',
        'value' => '*',
        'maxlength' => 6,
     ));
        
    
     $fieldset->addField('zipbasedprice_zip_from_zip', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'zipbasedprice_zip_from_zip',
        'label' => Mage::helper('zipbasedprice')->__('Zip Code From'),
        'class' => 'input',
        'required' => true,
    'style' => 'width:268px',
        'value' => '*',
        'maxlength' => 6,
     ));
     
      $fieldset->addField('zipbasedprice_zip_to_zip', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'zipbasedprice_zip_to_zip',
        'label' => Mage::helper('zipbasedprice')->__('Zip Code To'),
        'class' => 'input',
        'required' => true,
    'style' => 'width:268px',
        'value' => '*',
        'maxlength' => 6,
     ));
    
    $fieldset->addField('zipbasedprice_price', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'zipbasedprice_price',
        'label' => Mage::helper('zipbasedprice')->__('Price'),
        'class' => 'input',
        'required' => true,
        'style' => 'width:268px',
        'value' => '0.00',
     ));
    
    $fieldset->addField('zipbasedprice_apply', 'select', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('zipbasedprice')->__('Apply'),
        'name' => 'zipbasedprice_apply',
        'required' => false,
        'values' => array(
            array(
                'value' => 'fixed',
                'label' => Mage::helper('zipbasedprice')->__('Fixed'),
            ),
            array(
                'value' => 'percentage',
                'label' => Mage::helper('zipbasedprice')->__('Percentage'),
            )
        ),
        'required' => 1,
        'value' => 1,
        'style' => 'width:275px',
    ));
            
    return $form->toHtml();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different method to do this. Easiest and simplest method would be add an `onclick` property to the field to which another field depend upon. ie

```
$fieldset->addField('zipbasedprice_isrange', 'select', array(
    'name' => 'zipbasedprice_isrange',
    'label' => Mage::helper('zipbasedprice')->__('Is Range?'),
    ......
    'onclick' => someFunction();
```

and then define that `someFunction()` to achieve what you need.

Another alternative solution is shown in  [**this thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849616/can-a-magento-adminhtml-field-depend-on-more-then-one-field-or-value)

Answer (score 5):

Consider this example for showing a text field only when the `Specified` option is chosen.

```
$form = new Varien_Data_Form();

$form->addField('yesno', 'select', array(
    'label'  => $this->__('Yes or No?'),
    'values' => Mage::model('adminhtml/system_config_source_yesnocustom')
        ->toOptionArray(),
));

$form->addField('custom_value', text, array(
    'label'  => $this->__('Other'),
));

// Append dependency javascript
$this->setChild('form_after', $this->getLayout()
    ->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_form_element_dependence')
        ->addFieldMap('yesno', 'yesno')
        ->addFieldMap('custom_value', 'custom_value')
        ->addFieldDependence('custom_value', 'yesno', 2) // 2 = 'Specified'
);
```

**`depends`** – this node contains list of dependencies of the current field to other fields. The structure of this node is very simple. The child node name is name of field on what this one depends, and the node value is value for make this field visible. For example such configuration:

```
<depends>
     <field_name>1</field_name>
</depends>
```

The above will add rule for displaying of the current field only if the value of field called `field_name` equals to 1.

Comment: This is a new info for me. +1 for that. Where should we add depend nodes ? In layout files ?

Comment: That was an explaination.

Comment: ok. The code does not work for me. I have checked the code in my form, everything seems fine but still not able to achieve field dependency in my form. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I want to extends the answer from @Slimshadddyyy, putting another examples with more than one dependence values.

```
$fieldset->addField("transfer_interval", "select", array(
    "label" => Mage::helper("core")->__("Transfer Interval"),
    "name" => "transfer_interval",
    "class" => "required-entry",
    'values' => array(
        array(
            'value' => 'daily',
            'label' => Mage::helper('core')->__('Daily'),
        ),
        array(
            'value' => 'weekly',
            'label' => Mage::helper('core')->__('Weekly'),
        ),
        array(
            'value' => 'monthly',
            'label' => Mage::helper('core')->__('Monthly'),
        )
    ),
    "required" => true,
));

$fieldset->addField("transfer_day_weekly", "select", array(
    "label" => Mage::helper("core")->__("Transfer Day"),
    "name" => "transfer_day_weekly",
    "class" => "required-entry",
    'values' => $this->getWeekDays(), // Pay attention here you need to change this for your array values
    "required" => true,
));

$fieldset->addField("transfer_day_monthly", "select", array(
    "label" => Mage::helper("core")->__("Transfer Day"),
    "name" => "transfer_day_monthly",
    "class" => "required-entry",
    'values' => $this->getMontlyDays(), // Pay attention here you need to change this for your array values
    "required" => true,
));

// Append dependency javascript
$this->setChild('form_after', $this->getLayout()
    ->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_form_element_dependence')
    ->addFieldMap('transfer_interval', 'transfer_interval') // Putting fields for mapping
    ->addFieldMap('transfer_day_weekly', 'transfer_day_weekly')
    ->addFieldMap('transfer_day_monthly', 'transfer_day_monthly')
    ->addFieldDependence('transfer_day_weekly', 'transfer_interval', 'weekly') // Pay attetion below as you can add more than one dependence
    ->addFieldDependence('transfer_day_monthly', 'transfer_interval', 'monthly')
);
```

On this example, when you choose "Weekly" it will show field with weekly options and so if you choose "Monthly" option.